# Selective tar on Unix korn shell

Tags: unix, ksh

I need help to write a Korn Shell Script for Unix with the following features.

First of all, please suppose you have a Unix directory with the following content:

```
1) ALPHA_PIPPO_PLUTO_0001.xml
2) ALPHA_PIPPO_TOPOLINO_0001.xml
3) BETA_MINNIE_OMEGA_0002.xml
4) BETA_OMICRON_PHI_0002.xml
5) DELTA_WHY_NOT_0001.xml
6) DELTA_BECAUSE_WHY_0002.xml
```

Note that:

a) File 1 and File 2 begin with ALPHA and end with 0001: I have to create a tar file named ALPHA_0001.tar which contains these two files;

b) File 3 and File 4 begin with BETA and end with 0002: I have to create a tar file named BETA_0002.tar which contains these two files;

c) File 5 begins with DELTA and end with 0001: I have to create a tar file named DELTA_0001.tar which contains only this file;

d) File 6 begins with DELTA and end with 0002: I have to create a tar file named DELTA_0002.tar which containts only this file.

How could I achieve this in Unix Korn Shell?

Thank you very much for considering my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can archive it with this command:

```
find . -regex "^.*?_.*_.*?\.xml$" | sed -r "s|(^./[A-Z]*_).*_(.*?\.)xml$|tar -cvf \1\2tar|g" | sed -r "s|^.*\./([A-Z]*)_([0-9]*).tar|& \1*\2*|g" |  uniq | source /dev/stdin
```

Comment: ksh: source:  not found.
find: 0652-017 -regex is not a valid option.
sed: Not a recognized flag: r
Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
        sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]
sed: Not a recognized flag: r
Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
        sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]

Comment: Could you paste the output of `find --version` and `sed --version`?

Comment: Usage: find [-H | -L] Path-list [Expression-list]

Comment: sed --version
sed: Not a recognized flag: -
Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
        sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]
$